# Is this object mutable?

Tags: java, mutable

If I have a class like that:

```
public class MyObject {
    private int myField = 2;
    public void setMyField(int f) {
        this.myField = f;
    }
}
```

Will objects of this class be mutable?
Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Of course - if you want it to be immutable, then you need something like:

```
public class MyObject {
    private final int myField;

    public MyObject(int f) {
      myfield = f;
    }

    public int getMyField() {
        return myField;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can even make the `MyObject` class `final` to avoid suspicious overriding in some cases that may break this immutability. cf http://stackoverflow.com/a/5607360/985949

Answer (score 9):

### yes

> Mutable objects have fields that can be changed, immutable objects
>   have no fields that can be changed after the object is created.

Comment: Mutable objects have STATE. The above object does not expose any state, since there is no getter and the field is private.

Comment: @ChristianFries Of course it has state. It has `myField`. *And* it can  be changed through the setter, meaning it's mutable. That there's no getter is irrelevant.

Comment: @Christian I think (if I remember correctly from my OCA certification Exam) "mutable object can be modified after it is created" nothing else. No note about "get" or "set" (bean style).

Comment: Eventhough the state may not be visible it can still be viewed via reflection.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer: The object has state, but it does not expose it. I believe that an object of this class meets the definition of "effectively immutable". Reflection would work, but only if you modify the "private". In C++ I would suspect that a compiler would optimize the field and the setter away, if it realizes that the field is never read. - But, I do see your points.

Answer (score 6):

You already have several answers with a "**Yes**".

I would like to add a "**but**" (if I would be bold, I would say "**No**" ;-)

Yes, an object of this class *appears to be mutable*, since it provides a setter to change the field. However, since it does not have a getter for that field, neither any other getter depending on that field, and since the field is private, it is currently not possible to read that state.

Put differently: The object has state, but it does not expose any state to the outside.

I would call that object "effectively immutable".

There are some design patterns, where objects are "effectively immutable", for example "Lazy Initialization" of an "Immutable Object".

*Note:* The concept of being "effectively immutable" is discussed in Section 3.5.4 of Java Concurrency in Practice by Brian Goetz.

Comment: I know. I know (see also my comment above). But to do that you have to "modify" the private. And that way, you could make ANY object which is considered being (i.e. which "looks") immutable (also the ones in the other answers) mutable. I just wanted to mention "effectively immutable". The definition of "effectively immutable" relates to the way an object is used or intended to use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, objects of this class are mutable. The designer of the class can't prohibit by any technical means (in real existing Java) consumers of the objects to observe and modify the contents of the field.

*private* is an explicitly declared contract regarding intended usage of the field - this contract can be broken, e.g. with reflection.

Not providing any methods that change the data of an object after creation can also be a (implicitly declared) contract about intended use and mutability - this contract, too, can be broken, like any contract that needs two conforming parties.

Edit: Unless there is another party that has the means to *enforce* - like in Java the SecurityManager stopping you from changing a *final* field at runtime.

Comment: I am wondering if that definition (like being able to change a field via reflection) would actually imply that there are no immutable objects in Java.

Comment: If you don't want mutability don't use objects.

Answer (score 0):

***Yes***, your object is mutable as the value of `myField` can be changed after the instance is created using the setter.

Immutability can be achieved using `final` fields, as it will not allow you to change the value of a variable once it is initialized.

Answer by @JakubK points out how you can make your class Immutable.

But declaring reference `final` wont make the object being pointed by it `final`.

For example:

```
class MyObject{
    private final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public List<Integer> getList(){
        return list;
    }
}
```

I can change add a new element to the `list` from outside by doing something like this

```
instance.getList().add(1); //mutates the list
```

This example is not immutable, as the List can be changed by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

To define whether something is mutable, one has to define what state is encapsulated thereby.  If `MyObject` specifies that its state includes the value which Reflection will report for `myField`, then it is mutable.  If that field is not specified as being part of the object's observable state, then it may be most purposes regarded as immutable.

To be more specific, I would regard a class as being immutable only if one could perform any combination of documented operations upon the class, in any sequence and with any timing (even on multiple threads), and not have any documented behavioral aspects of of any of them affected by any other.  The fact that a method might change the contents of a private field is relevant if and only if that change would affect some documented behavioral aspect of another method call (to the same or different method).  For example, I would say that the fact that `String.hashCode()` modifies the `hash` field does not make `String` mutable, because the value returned by `hashCode()` is not affected by whether or not the field had been written previously.  If a class had a `hashCode` method which would, if a field was blank, generate a random number and store it in that field, and otherwise return the value directly, such a class would be mutable unless it ensured that the field was tested and set as an atomic operation.  In the absence of such assurance, it would be possible for near-simultaneous calls to `hashCode()` to yield different values, and thus for future calls to differ values that would differ from at least one of them (implying that the object's state had changed between the call that returned the odd-ball value and the later call).